# Service account with only objectViewer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Cloud Registry for docker images and want to create a service account that can´t push images to the registry, just pull.

When I creates a service account it inherits my permissions and I can´t remove the unwanted permissions.

What am I missing?

Comment: My goal was to create a service account with only role `storage.objectViewer` according to [GC Configuring Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles)

Comment: I have the same problem - all of my service accounts seem to inherit "Cloud Functions Service Agent", "Cloud ML Service Agent", "Compute Engine Service Agent", "Editor", "Kubernetes Engine Service Agent", "Owner" and "Service Account Actor"

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a new service account through IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts). During the process of account creation, you can choose the IAM roles you want to assign it.

In the case where you have already created the service account and it has inherited permissions you don't want it to use, you can go to IAM and [change the roles assigned](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) to the service account

Comment: The I can't remove the inherited permissions and each service account I creates inherits my permissions. 
This explanation is shown in a tooltip "Member is inherited from another policy and cannot be deleted". I dpn't understand the explanation.

Comment: How are you creating the service account and at what level? When you create a service account at the project level using the UI, you should not receive this message